# Check if a specific word in a string contains capital using Powershell

Tags: powershell, case-sensitive

I am checking a registry key using `get-childitem` with the `-recurse` option. I am piping that into `Get-ItemProperty`, where I'm looking for a specific value of a string value. I am then selecting that object. I want to further enhance my script to add an `If` statement. I only want to do something If one word in my string contains a capital letter. The trick is, only that specific word and no other words.

The value of my string value looks like this:  `Https:\\Blah.blah.com`

So in the above, only the `if` statement to be true if "https" contains a capital.  Above, it does contain a capital.  If however the value returned is something like `https:\\CapitalLettersHereareOK.com`. Then the `If` statement should return false.

I can't use `-cmatch` because, while it works, it's matching the entire string. As outlined above, some of the letters in the string could be capital, and that is ok. I just need to know if "HTTPS" contains any capital letters.

I'm no good at Regex and I'm pretty sure that is needed here. See code below:

```
$GetWebValue = Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\Software\MySoftwareKey' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Get-ItemProperty -Name Web -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-object -expandproperty Web
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to **isolate the protocol name** (everything before `:`) and **test only *it* for the presence of uppercase characters**; e.g.:

```
PS> ('Https:\\Blah.blah.com' -split ':')[0] -cmatch '\p{Lu}'
True  # ditto for 'httpS:\\...', 'hTtps:\\...', 'HTTPS:\\...', ...

PS> ('https:\\Blah.blah.com' -split ':')[0] -cmatch '\p{Lu}'
False
```

- `(... -split ':')[0]` extracts the first `:` based token from the LHS string, i.e., the protocol name.
- `-cmatch` case-*sensitively* matches regex `\p{Lu}` (an uppercase letter) anywhere  in that protocol name.

  - Note: In this simple case, where it's safe to assume that only *ASCII-range* letters `a` through `z` can be part of a protocol name, regex `[A-Z]` would suffice; by contrast, `\p{Lu}` matches any uppercase *Unicode* character classified as a letter.

---

In the context of your command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\Software\MySoftwareKey' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
  Get-ItemProperty Web -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Web |
      Where-Object { ($_ -split ':')[0] -cmatch '\p{Lu}' }
```

Note that while you *should* be able to use `Get-ItemPropertyValue Web` (PSv5+) instead of the roundabout `Get-ItemProperty Web | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Web`, so as to directly extract just the *data* from each matching registry value, this is *not* an option as of this writing, due to a [known bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5906).